# Compare two array values based on common characters using PHP

Tags: arrays

I have two arrays as

```
$array1 = array('Visa Inc', 'Microsoft Corporation', 'Apple Inc');
$array2 = array('visa', 'microsoft', 'apple', 'amazon');
```

Now I want to get the output by comparing two arrays with common characters of values like:

```
$result = array('Visa Inc', 'Microsoft Corporation', 'Apple Inc');
```

Please help me if there is any possible way to get my required output? Kindly suggest me a procedure to obtain the results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Custom php code for compare arrays

```
 <?php
    $array1 = array('Visa Inc', 'Microsoft Corporation', 'Apple Inc');
    $array2 = array('visa', 'microsoft', 'apple', 'amazon');

    $newArray = [];

    $total = count($array1);
    $sec   = count($array2);

    for($i=0; $i <= $sec; $i++)
    {
        for($j=0; $j <= $total; $j++)
        {
            $name = $array1[$j];
            $com  = explode(" ",$name);
            $newName = strtolower($com[0]);
            if($array2[$i] == $newName)
            {
                $newArray[] = $array1[$j];
            }
        }
    }

    $result = array_filter($newArray, function($var){return !is_null($var);} );  // remove empty fields

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($result);
```

Comment: Thank you Mr. Aman Kumar. This helps me to get my job done. Thanks a ton